# How does this volume look like?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling to understand how does the volume look like in this question:

> Find plane $z=a$ that cuts the volume of: 
> $V=\{ (x,y,z)| 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$ into two cuts with same volume.

I'm struggling and getting confused in knowing what is $V$. 
I can see it as a Cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ that goes from $z$ to $1$ while $z$ is some plane (as they've said in the question). 
But if I do that, and I want to calculate the whole volume of $V$ first to find $a$: 
$D: x^2+y^2 \le 1$ 
$\iint_D(\int_0^1dz)dxdy=\iint_Ddxdy=\pi$.
So $\iint_D(\int_a^1dz)dxdy=\frac{\pi}{2}$. 
$\iint_D(1-a)dxdy=(1-a)\iint_Ddxdy=(1-a)\pi=\frac{\pi}{2} \Longrightarrow 1-a=\frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow a=\frac{1}{2}$. 

But the answer is actually $a=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. 
So I started to think I got $V$ wrong, and tried to think about it like this: 
If $z \le x^2+y^2 \le 1$. that means I'm taking all the points that are above the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and under the plane $z=1$. 
But at the same time I can't see why is this $V$, since if it was I would've seen $x^2+y^2 \le z \le 1$. 
I would appreciate it if someone could clear things up for me and tell me how do you in general know what the surface is.

Comment: $z\le x^2+y^2$ means you are taking the points **below** the paraboloid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me describe the situation and then you can use geogebra yourself to see it.

$V=\{ (x,y,z)| 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$

So the region is bound between surfaces

$z = x^2+y^2, x^2+y^2 = 1, z = 0$

The intersection of cylinder and paraboloid is at $z = 1$. That gives the upper bound of $z$.

And clearly for $z \leq 1$, paraboloid surface is inside the cylinder as $\sqrt z \leq 1$.

In cylindrical coordinates, the region is

$\sqrt z \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq 1$

Now if a plane $z = a$ intersects this region, $a \lt 1$. As the plane is parallel to $xy-$ plane, it is easier to integrate wrt $dr$ first. One of the sub-regions is bound between $0 \leq z \leq a$ and the other is bound between $a \leq z \leq 1$.

That should lead you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your volume looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, could you please approve this: So what I see is from the inequality $0 \le z \le x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, is that I'm taking all the points under the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, but that paraboloid is bounded from above by the plane $z=1$ and by the plane $z=0$ from below. I'm struggling a little to set it into the integral and would appreciate it if you could help

Comment: Bad form to ask a question, receive an answer (that is accepted), and then say... "no wait... my *REAL* question was something else."

Comment: I guess if you look at it like that, but what I'm just trying to understand how do I reach the picture you provided from what I have, I've explained in the question body what I tried to do so I expected an answer with a little explanation on how to "see" the volume, showing me this pictured helped me find how to "see" it, and I wanted an approval, if you don't want to approve or help anymore, that's fine. My bad for not asking a full question.